# How do you set ImageMagick font path for SVG conversion?

Tags: php, css, svg, fonts

I've got a test SVG here using Lobster:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="2400" height="3200" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <defs>
        <style>
            @import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster');
        </style>
    </defs>
    <text id="SvgjsText1046" font-family="Lobster" fill="#000000" font-size="30px" stroke-width="0" font-style="" font-weight="" text-decoration=" " x="859.9871134019216" y="476.38530927854697" transform="rotate(0 1214.8671520099174 1164.5108891121047) translate(-9360.999092988961 -5185.475896759851) scale(11.885045772324295 11.885045772324297) ">
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1072" dy="29">TEST</tspan>
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1073" dy="29">TEST</tspan>
        <tspan id="SvgjsTspan1074" dy="29">TEST</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

This renders fine in the browser, but when converting to a PNG in ImageMagick (using php), the font doesn't render.

I know you can use the setFont command to set a single font, but the SVG may contain multiple fonts.

In this instance, is there any way to set a font directory for ImageMagick?

Answer (score 0):

From the manual it seems that there is no way to import a font directory.
May be i'm wrong btw.

**Alternatives**

In the manual there is [ImagickDraw::setFont](http://php.net/manual/en/imagickdraw.setfont.php) which allow you to use multiple fonts.

Consider that with this method you have to draw the text, It's not exactly for conversion but may be it can be usefull.

Comment: Thanks for the info. That seems to be a problem as I'll have to take an SVG with N number of fonts and build a composite with other images. Is this something GD can do just as easily?